# How do I presign url of PutObjectCommand with certain headers?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am new to aws-sdk and I want to sign Cache-Control, Content-Type and x-amz-acl headers for presigned url. Is it possible to do with s3-request-presigner? I can't find any example.

```js
var command = new PutObjectCommand({
  Bucket: 'mybucket',
  Key: 'file.txt',
  ACL: 'public-read',
  CacheControl: 'public, max-age=1000',
  ContentType: 'text/plain',
  });

var signedUrl = await getSignedUrl(s3Client, command, {
  expiresIn: 3600, 
  signableHeaders: 
    new Set(['Cache-Control', 'Content-Type', 'x-amz-acl'])
});
```

The resulting url contains this: X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host. That is, my headers
don't get signed. What do I have to do?

Also, can I restrain the size of the upload with something like content-length-range and sign it as well?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably solved this by now, but what XHR client were you using?

I had the same issue using axios because I was calling axios like this:

```
axios({
    url: signedRequest,
    method: 'put',
    data: Body,
    headers: {
      'x-amz-acl': 'public-read-write',
      'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
    },
    maxContentLength: Infinity,
    maxBodyLength: Infinity
  })
```

I needed to remove the `headers` property in this axios call because I was already setting `ACL` and `ContentType` when getting the signed request. Once I remove the `headers` property from my axios call, it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Headers in the `signableHeaders` set should be lowercased to match those from the PUT object command.

```
var signedUrl = await getSignedUrl(s3Client, command, {
  expiresIn: 3600, 
  signableHeaders: 
    new Set(['cache-control', 'content-type', 'x-amz-acl'])
});
```

> All headers in the provided request will have their names converted to lower case before signing.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-appconfigdata/interfaces/requestpresigningarguments.html